# Extracting data using JQ

Tags: json, dictionary, jq

I am trying to use jq to extract data from JSON fields that contain a specific value.

This is the JSON that I'm working with:

```
{
  "thing1": {
    "a": false,
    "b": true,
    "c": false,
    "d": false
  },
  "thing2": {
    "a": true,
    "b": true,
    "c": true,
    "d": true
  },
  "thing3": {
    "a": true,
    "b": false,
    "c": false,
    "d": false
  }
}
```

I want to retain the objects that contain `"true"` values, and to remove keys whose value is not `true`.

I don't have much experience with JQ, nor how to properly structure json data. If this means restructuring the primary JSON data, I'm open to do that as well.

Here is the result I'm trying to achieve:

```
{
  "thing1": {
    "b": true
  },
  "thing2": {
    "a": true,
    "b": true,
    "c": true,
    "d": true
  },
  "thing3": {
    "a": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# First remove the subkeys that are not truthy:
map_values(with_entries(select(.value)))
# ... then remove the empty dictionaries:
| with_entries(select(.value|length > 0))
```

Add seasoning to taste.

Comment: This worked great for boolean values... by chance is there a way to do this with non-boolean values? Say if the fields were "Success" or "Failure" instead of true/false

Comment: @Chris - Of course. jq is a programming language.  You'd just modify the `select(.value)` expression to specify the criteria you want, e.g. `select(.value != "Failure")`

Answer (score 0):

Another jq script:

```
<file jq 'del(..|select(. == false))'
```

This recursively goes to all nodes (operator `..`) and deletes all elements whose value would be `false`.

If needed, you can change the criteria in the `select` with something else than `false`, for example `"Failure"`.